# Adding dataSource to tableView without interfase and display it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have intreface:

```
@interface Box : CDVPlugin <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

Now after an event I want to display tableView with diffrent kind of data.
I created a tableView and adde it...its working

```
UITableView *tView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
      [[self.webView superview] addSubview:tView];
```

How can I connect it do a dataSource??

I tried adding:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

but it's never stops there and the table is always empty.
How to coonect it to data (NSMutableArray)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never telling the table View who's the dataSource

You can do it like this:

```
UITableView *tView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
tView.dataSource = self; // or something else
tView.delegate = self; // or something else
[[self.webView superview] addSubview:tView];
```

DataSource is for the creation of the cells (cellForRowAtIndex:, numberOfRowsInSection:, etc)
Delegate is for actions, like (didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: I tried it, added : `tView.dataSource = self;` but nothing changed....doest it suppose to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? or should I trasnfer to `mapView.dataSource` an array?

Comment: There's a series of minimal dataSource functions that you need, which are numberOfSectionsInTableView:, numberOfRowsInSection:, and cellForRowAtIndexPath:

You should check if you are actually telling the tableView it has cells (that means, check if the number of sections you are returning is greater than 0, and if the number of rows for a given section is greater than 0)

Comment: It worked!! thank's!!! so the tView.dataSource = self; saying to use the tableView functions that are written in that interface?